# Font and other considerations when writing a book

Tags: ebook

Which font are mainly using writers, while `writing a Book` and also what things should be kept in mind while being a Writer.

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with either hardware or software.

Comment: Daniel Beck :) it is related to font in Microsoft words definitely software

Comment: *Everything* is based on "hardware" and controlled by "software". That doesn't make your car or your microwave on-topic either.

Comment: Other considerations? Get a good editor, and use grammar check. "font are mainly using writers" is really bad form for a writer.

Comment: Also, get a proof reader who has your language as their second language as 'foreigners' are often taught a much purer form of the grammar and syntax and spot/query easily-missed mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generalise, [serif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif) fonts are considered best for readability where long paragraphs of text are concerned (ie: a book). Which one to use may depend on personal preference or the [style guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide) issued by the publisher.

Some popular ones for books are:

- Times/[Times Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_Roman)
- [Georgia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_%28typeface%29)
- [Century Schoolbook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_Type_Family)

If you are going to write a book of any decent length in Word, a few guidelines:

- Backup your work frequently and keep a number of versions so you can backtrack if needed.
- Setup and use the Word styles so you can easily change fonts/formatting of the whole document easily. (I can't emphasise this enough)
- If your book is going to include a significant number of images, consider a proper [DTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_publishing) package instead of Word. Maintaining image placement in long documents in Word is better than it once was, but it can still go horribly wrong or waste a lot of your time.
- Use separate document files for separate chapters - don't keep everything in one big document - and check out how Word can handle such multi-file documents to produce indexes.
- Many publishers will expect the source material in DTP format so if the book is going to be handed to a publisher check what they would prefer.
- Really really consider a DTP package. Free ones are available - have a look at [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus).
- If your 'book' is going to be published as an 'ebook' you can use a wider range of fonts as the amount of text the reader sees at a time can be controlled by them to improve readability.

Comment: ) Download it, but i don't no how to use Scribus.

Comment: Except that for *writing* the book, most often a monospace font was used (or still is). This allows to quickly judge the content length based on line width, lines per page and page count.

Comment: A4 - typically 900 words per page was the magazine standard. Agreed, though, page count is important but these days the WP/DTP packages produce the stats and then pre-publication editing hones things to the right size, but it can be a challenge if an eye is not kept on desired length from the outset.